# Set Autorecovery enabled Spring amqp rabbitmq in xml

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

With rabbitmq client i can make it work with following bean inject well i heard  CachingConnectionFactory has another constructor to apply a `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory`, which will help to enable auto recovery, but it has limited attributes to go with it.

```
<bean id="rcf" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
<property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="580" />
<property name="topologyRecoveryEnabled" value="true" />
<property name="automaticRecoveryEnabled" value="true" />
</bean>
```

But when it comes to spring amqp for rabbit , i found no options to do that.

I appreciate , Any help regarding the query i raised ..

This is really interesting and one of the important communication problem that we need solve when we are going to work under single Message Bus Architecture.  Since, we are planning to abstracted out the internal details of Message Bus, it is necessary to provide what type of attributes that we need to enable in consumer as well as producer end.

This is my consumer.xml

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
        host="${rabbitmq.host}" virtual-host="${rabbitmq.vhost}" username="${rabbitmq.user}" password="${rabbitmq.password}" />
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
<rabbit:queue id="mQueue" name="${rabbitmq.queue.m}" />
<rabbit:queue id="mrQueue" name="${rabbitmq.queue.mr}" />
```

Can you explain how to set auto recovery in this xml? Please add xml which will set auto recovery with above consumer xml

Answer (score 0):

Spring AMQP has (and has always had) it's own connection recovery mechanism. The rabbit client added it much later and it's mechanism is incompatible with Spring AMQP. Setting `automaticRecoveryEnabled` will cause problems with Spring AMQP versions prior to 1.4.0.

1.4.0 and later are compatible with the rabbitmq settings, but still uses its own recovery mechanism.

You can change the `recoveryInterval` on the message listener container (default 5 seconds).

Comment: can you please tell how to set recoveryinterval in producer.xml

Comment: this is my producer.xml 
        <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
                host="${rabbitmq.host}" virtual-host="${rabbitmq.vhost}" username="${rabbitmq.user}" password="${rabbitmq.password}" channel-cache-size="10"/>

        <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" id="rabbitadmin" />
..................... etc                 I search in google find nothing ,as per my search . can you help me in having recovery interval in producer.xml,

Comment: Don't post code/config in comments - it's unreadable. Please edit the question instead.

Comment: There's no recovery required on the producer side; the broken channel will be created on demand. You can enable retry in the rabbit template if needed.

Comment: ======================== Let's assume i want to set recovery interval in consumer side . can tell me how to have auto recovery in below xml. http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.3.xsd ">
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"           host="${rabbitmq.host}" virtual-host="${rabbitmq.vhost}" username="${rabbitmq.user}" password="${rabbitmq.password}" />
 <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:queue id="a" name="${rabbitmq.queue.a}" />

Comment: Don't post code/config in comments; it's unreadable; edit the question instead. On the consumer side, the recovery-interval is set on the listener container (default 5 seconds). See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#containerAttributes). If you are consuming using `template.receive()`, the connection will be re-established on demand.